# How to downsize an image using bilinear filtering in Swift/iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing

I need to resize an image using bilinear filtering but not sure how this can be done in Swift.   In Python, PIL as well as Opencv allows us to choose an interpolation method when resizing (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html). I was hoping to mimic the process in iOS for a coreML model

I searched around for resizing methods but this is what I was able to find via a blog:

```
extension UIImage {
    func resizeUI(size:CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, self.scale)
        self.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))

        let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return resizedImage
   }
```

However, it doesn't seem to allow you to choose the interpolation methods.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I found `imageBySamplingLinear`, but this method doesn't allow you to resize the image using an interpolation method. It just takes the current sized image and interpolates it?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage/2867346-imagebysamplinglinear?language=objc

While the real algorithm resizes the image using the interpolation:

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation#Python

Comment: I've never heard of bilinear filtering before now (I had to look the term up) but maybe this may help. It describes a way to resize using Lanczos sampling. Money quote: *"My first step was to use Lanczos resampling rather than simply relying on drawInRect() at the new size. Lanczos offers smooth resampling which should lead to a better quality image and it's available as one of the built in Core Image filters."* Also, his old code is linked above this quote. http://flexmonkey.blogspot.com/2014/12/scaling-resizing-and-orienting-images.html

Comment: Thank you! taking a look at it now. In Python, PIL as well as Opencv allows us to choose an interpolation method when resizing (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html). I was hoping to mimic the process in iOS for a coreML model.